# Set textbox in template width fitful with column width

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Say I have to customize the cell template.

```
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="*">
         <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" Padding="2 0 2 0" Width="160" />
               </DataTemplate>
         </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Address}" Width="2*">
         <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Address}" Margin="2" Padding="2 0 2 0" Width="360" />
               </DataTemplate>
         </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

My question is I don't know the width of the column, so I hard code the textbox's width as 160 or 360. And I adjust the width by visual appearance manually.

So can w bind it to the column's width?

Comment: Why do you specify an explicit TextBox width in the first place?

Comment: @mm8, because the width of the textbox is small by default. It can not display the whole text. But the column's width is big. I want them match. So I force the width is equal a big value.

Comment: The TextBox should stretch horizontally to fill the column by default, i.e. if you don't set the Width property at all.

Comment: I have the default global style for textbox. I can't change it as it impacts everywhere. So I want to override it.

Comment: Did you try `Width = "Auto"`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It is not working.

Comment: You may want to include your "default global style" in the question if you want anyone to be able to help you. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
Width={Binding ElementName=ColumnName , Path=Width}
```

Or you can set your TextBox width

> width="auto"

So its gonna fit to text width , or if u don't put width , not sure about this one but, it's gonna take width of it's parent element(don't take my word for last one).